# Handle multiple SampleGrabber

Tags: c#, directx, directshow, multimedia, directshow.net

I created a graph which has two SampleGrabbers. When I want to set callback function, I use this code for both SampleGrabbers:

```
SetCallback(this, 1);
```

Both SampleGrabbers use my BufferCB function. When I get a frame in BufferCB function, how can I understand that frame is for first SampleGrabber or the second one?

Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To distinguish between grabbers you need to have different instances of the object you implement your callback on.

See more: [Using multiple sample grabbers](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/d79011a8-23c0-4485-a538-b2141a57c4b8/using-multiple-sample-grabbers).